# Format of f string example

Tags: python, f-string, format-string

I have an example of f strings in  textbook, it's a function whose purpose is to take a list and print the list out enumerated, I do not understand how the code is functioning but do know it works fine. I would like to understand a few things about this code:

```
import random
OPTIONS = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

def print_options():
    print('\n'.join(f'({i}) {option.title()}' for i,option in enumerate(OPTIONS)))


print_options()
```

output:

```
(1) Rock
(2) Paper
(3) Scissors
```

the problem line is the body of the function. I would like to see how to modify the line but preserving the f-string method to leave out the enumeration, e.g.

desired output:

```
Rock
Paper
Scissors
```

All I can think of is:

```
def _print_choices():
    print('\n.join(f'({choice.title()}))' for choice in choices)

print_choices()
```

Which I can see from the amount of red in the editor is not even worth running.

Any ideas?

Comment: The answers below are correct, but just fyi: you don't need the f-string, the `title()` method or even the function definition. Just `print('\n'.join(option for option in OPTIONS))` or without list comprehension or the need for `\n`: `for option in OPTIONS:
    print(option)`.

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you for that. I just wanted to see how to use the f-string method on a simpler example so that I could understand the example in the book. You're totally right there is no need for the f-string to give the output I required it is just to help me learn f-strings as I was a bit mystified as to what the inside of the textbook's function was doing before Richard and Eric's answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def print_options():
    print('\n'.join(option.title() for option in OPTIONS))

# output: 
# Rock 
# Paper 
# Scissors
```

Since you don't want the index, the f-string and enumeration can be totally removed.

Comment: Apologies, I did not format the desired output correctly, have fixed it now, each list element was supposed to be on a new line.

Comment: Hi Richard, I'm going to accept yours. Out of interest how would it have looked with the f_string (even though it is superfluous).I ask because I don't get why the textbook had the enumerate index part of the fstring inside so many brackets, e.g. ({I})

Comment: @Windy71 Within f-strings, to reference a name (variable or function) you need to wrap it in `{}` (see https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#simple-syntax for more info). 

The additional `()` around those was just for print output styling purposes, i.e. `(1)` instead of just `1`.

Comment: Ahh you star, I never got that. Thank you Richard that is a brilliant answer.

Answer (score 1):

```py
OPTIONS = ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')
def _print_choices(OPTIONS, sep='\n'):
    print(sep.join([f'{choice.title()}' for choice in OPTIONS]))
```

Output:

```
>>> _print_choices(OPTIONS, '\n'):
Rock
Paper
Scissors
```

Comment: Apologies, I did not format the desired output correctly, have fixed it now, each list element was supposed to be on a new line.

Comment: Try this. Also made it more dynamic (pass the choices and the separator as the arguments)

Comment: Thank you very much Eric Jin, much appreciated!